# Falha ao gerar arquivo TXT por meio de rotina para impressão no VBA/Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, impressão

O formulário apresentado abaixo refere-se ao código em **VBA** (Excel) apresentado adiante.

[image: Formulário do VBA/Excel com dois botões para impressão em arquivo]

Este código refere-se à impressão de uma planilha em **Excel** de nome "**Impressão**", conforme mostra a figura abaixo. Pelos parâmetros passados em cada botão, serão impressos todos os dados que constarem nesta planilha, ou seja, não é a impressão de uma determinada "faixa de células".

[image: Aba da planilha em Excel a ser impressa em arquivo]

No formulário do **VBA** os dois botões têm o nome de:

```
CommandButtonImprimeEmPDF

CommandButtonImprimeEmTXT
```

E no código há a rotina `ImprimeOuSalvaEmArquivo` destinada à impressão ou salvamento (de forma genérica), sendo neste caso testada a impressão em arquivos.

Verifica-se no código que para o mesmo "**Path**" e "**nome de arquivo**" informados, conforme o evento "click" de cada botão, a extensão muda nos parâmetros passados para a rotina de impressão, de **PDF** para **TXT** respectivamente.

Ao acionar cada botão, são apresentadas as mensagens abaixo informando o local, o nome e a extensão dos arquivos gerados.

[image: Mensagem do sucesso da impressão do segundo arquivo]

[image: Mensagem do sucesso da impressão do primeiro arquivo]

A figura abaixo mostra o resultado na **pasta**, onde os arquivos foram gerados corretamente quanto ao **local, nome e extensão**.

[image: Pasta com os arquivos salvos]

Ao abrir o arquivo em **PDF** ele está como previsto, porém o arquivo em **TXT** não, ou seja, **ele não apresenta o texto da planilha como esperado (em formato texto)**.

O código segue abaixo:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub CommandButtonImprimeEmPDF_Click()

     'Salva impressão como arquivo em PDF
     ImprimeOuSalvaEmArquivo "Impressão", _
                             "", _
                             True, _
                             "F:\Teste\TesteDeImpressao1.PDF", _
                             False, _
                             "", _
                             1, _
                             True

     'Veja o significado das opções na rotina de impressão e salvamento

     End Sub


     Private Sub CommandButtonImprimeEmTXT_Click()

      'Salva impressão como arquivo em TXT
      ImprimeOuSalvaEmArquivo "Impressão", _
                              "", _
                              True, _
                              "F:\Teste\TesteDeImpressao1.TXT", _
                              False, _
                              "", _
                              1, _
                              True

     'Veja o significado das opções na rotina de impressão e salvamento

    End Sub


    Private Sub ImprimeOuSalvaEmArquivo( _
                ByVal NomeDaPlanilha As String, _
       Optional ByVal FaixaParaImprimir As String = "", _
       Optional ByVal ImprimirEmArquivo As Boolean = False, _
       Optional ByVal CaminhoNomeExtensaoDoArquivo As String = "", _
       Optional ByVal SelecionarImpressora As Boolean = False, _
       Optional ByVal NomeInternoDaImpressora As String = "", _
       Optional ByVal NumeroDeCopias As String = 1, _
       Optional ByVal MensagemAoFinalDaImpressao = False)

     Dim Planilha As Object

     'O objeto Planilha assume a planilha selecionada
     Set Planilha = Sheets(NomeDaPlanilha) 'Planilha anteriormente selecionada

     'Ativa a planilha a salvar/imprimir
     Planilha.Activate

     'Se optou por selecionar a impressora
     'e não solicitou salvar em arquivo
     If SelecionarImpressora _
        And Not ImprimirEmArquivo Then

         Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

     End If

     'Se o nome da impressora não foi informado anteriormente
     If NomeInternoDaImpressora = "" Then

         'Pega o nome da impressora ativa
         NomeInternoDaImpressora = ActivePrinter

     End If

     'Faixa a imprimir ou toda a planilha se vier com ""
     Planilha.PageSetup.PrintArea = FaixaParaImprimir

     'Imprime ou salva em arquivo
     ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut _
         Copies:=NumeroDeCopias, _
         ActivePrinter:=NomeInternoDaImpressora, _
         PrintToFile:=ImprimirEmArquivo, _
         PrToFileName:=CaminhoNomeExtensaoDoArquivo

     Beep

     'Se solicitou mensagem de local e nome do arquivo salvo/impresso
     If MensagemAoFinalDaImpressao Then

         MsgBox "Local e Nome do Arquivo Salvo/Impresso: " _
                & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
                CaminhoNomeExtensaoDoArquivo

     End If

 End Sub
```

Testei alterando os **nomes internos das impressoras** que tenho, eles diferem dos nomes presentes na lista abaixo, foi preciso pegar esses nomes por meio de código pelo **VBA** após selecionar a impressora e usando um **MsgBox**, por exemplo. Conforme a figura abaixo, foram gerados arquivos **TXT** em vários formatos, menos no pretendido (não apresentei aqui esses testes, pois foram um para cada impressora da lista).

[image: Impressoras disponíveis]

**Uma observação**: caso a opção de impressão em arquivo seja passada no respectivo parâmetro, não é apresentada a caixa de diálogo para a seleção da impressora mesmo que isso tenha sido solicitado pelo seu parâmetro. Caso queira testar a impressão para arquivos usando a seleção de impressora esta parte do código precisa ser adaptada.

Sei que há outras formas de gerar arquivos **TXT**, por exemplo, por meio de **macro**, mas gostaria de usar a rotina que apresentei já que ela apresenta várias possibilidades de tratar a impressão, como a inclusão dos títulos e modificação das margens (aqui a rotina está simplificada).

Em referência à instrução usada (`ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut`) não 
encontrei como gerar corretamente o arquivo **TXT** nem se isso é possível por meio dela.

Gostaria de saber se **faltou indicar algo nesta instrução** ou se **ela não faz o que pretendo**, gerar arquivos **TXT** de forma a apresentar a mesma disposição dos dados da planilha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, pensei em **gerar uma impressora que só imprimisse em arquivo texto**, pesquisei e achei este link:

http://faq.altoqi.com.br/content/365/862/pt-br/configurando-uma-impressora-generica_somente-texto.html

Apesar de ser um exemplo em versão anterior do Windows, eu segui os passos e adaptei para o meu caso conforme apresento a sequência que segue abaixo.

1. Adicionar uma **impressora**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Impressora **Local**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Porta **LPT1**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Fabricante "**Generic**" e Impressora "**Generic / Text Only**"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. **Nome da Impressora**. Deixei o padrão "**Generic / Text Only**":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

6. Compartilhamento, **optei por não compartilhar**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

7. Concluir (**desmarquei a opção de "definir como padrão"**)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Foi gerada a impressora abaixo**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Criei um botão "Imprimir"** para fazer o novo teste, e adaptei os parâmetros de impressão para que **seja solicitada a impressora** antes de imprimir:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonImprimir_Click()

 ImprimeOuSalvaEmArquivo "Impressão", _
                         "", _
                         False, _
                         "F:\Teste\TesteDeImpressao2.TXT", _
                         True, _
                         "", _
                         1, _
                         True

End Sub
```

Repare que alterei não só o nome do arquivo, mas que ativei o parâmetro de "**selecionar impressora**".

A impressora para arquivos textos surgiu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A impressão saiu como desejado, porém reparei **um cactere no final da impressão**. Vou fazer outra pergunta relativa à isso, pois não tenho ideia se tem como fazer para não sair este caractere ao gerar o arquivo texto. **O link desta nova questão é**:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137191/caractere-surge-no-final-ao-gerar-impress%C3%A3o-em-arquivo-texto-no-vba-excel